# javascript access to network panel info

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, google-chrome

I would like to get information similar to what is in the Network tab of the Developer Tools panel in Chrome. Or even Net panel of Firebug in Firefox. Even scrapping it would be fine. I am building a internal tool that looks for specific elements, and builds out an "audit" results. I would need information like Time/Latency and Initiator (if available). I thought WebTiming was what I wanted, but that only shows the totals, not individual items broken out... unless I'm using it incorrectly. Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 2):

I have a suspicion that in order to do what the net panel does, or the network tab, or what fiddler does, there is some actual monitoring of protocols and ports.

Assuming that is true, I'm not confident you can do that with javascript; I would imagine that javascript's execution space is within the scope of the browser, whereas those plugins / programs have broader scope and thus access to the protocols and things.

Comment: But aren't they just extensions? The final plan is to make this an extension, so I should in theory have the same privileges as them right?

Comment: The extensions are attached to the program which has privs within the computer. Javascript is just a script that is rendered within the browser. According to your post title, you'd like to do this with javascript, which lead me to believe you were writing a web page of some kind, in which this would not be achievable in JS. However, if you're going to write an extension, you've got to look up the API the for the browser itself so you can consume that data they've exposed